# Pass current file name from loop to label in batch script

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, sqlcmd

In a batch script I'm running sqlcmd in a loop that goes through a folder of SQL scripts. I would like to be able to pass the script/output file currently being worked on to a label exterior to the loop in the case of an error.

Here's sample code:

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET _INSTANCE=someinstance
SET _DATABASE=somedatabase
SET "_SCRIPTFOLDER=D:\Scripts for Testing"
SET "_OUTPUTFOLDER=D:\Output for Testing"

FOR %%S IN (
    "%_SCRIPTFOLDER%\*.sql"
) DO (

    SET /P _MSGa=Generating CSV: %%~nS.csv ... <NUL

    sqlcmd -b -S %_INSTANCE% -d %_DATABASE% -i "%%~fS" -s "|" -o "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nS.csv" -W
    IF ERRORLEVEL >= 1 GOTO sqlcomderrorhandling

    SET /P _MSGb=file created. Removing header dashes ... <NUL

    REM REM Remove the line with dashes below the header
    @FINDSTR /r /b /v /c:"-*|" "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nS.csv" > "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%"\tmp.txt
    IF ERRORLEVEL >= 1 GOTO findstrerrorhandling

    XCOPY /Y "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%"\tmp.txt "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nS.csv" >NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL >= 1 GOTO copyerrorhandling

    ECHO done.
)
DEL /Q /F "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%"\tmp.txt
GOTO done

:sqlcomderrorhandling
ECHO An error occurred while processing the file %%~nS.csv

:done
@pause
```

The last ECHO just outputs %~nS.csv, not the actual name of the CSV file. Do I need to utilize functions in some way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type: `IF /?` to read the help file for the IF command.

Comment: @Squashman, I did as you suggested. I also did some Googling on IF, but I'm not seeing anything that's directly relevant to what I'm asking about, sorry.

Comment: Yep.  Instead of `>=` you need `geq`.  Also, `if (not) errorlevel n` already assumes greater-than-or-equal, so you really don't need the `geq` operator at all.  Alternatively, you could use conditional execution.  `findstr blah blah || goto errorlabel` will goto errorlabel if the exit code of findstr is non-zero.

Comment: Okay, how to handle the error isn't my question - how to pass the currenly-handled file name to label exterior to the for loop is what I'm asking about. Unless you answered that and I'm not understanding your answer...

Comment: If you use a `GOTO` you will break the loop and you will not process anymore files.  You sure you do not want to use a `CALL` which will run the label and return back into the `FOR` command?  If you use the GOTO, you need to assign the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable before the GOTO. The FOR variable only exists within the scope of the FOR command.

Comment: @marky You can either `set "filename=%_OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nS.csv"` and access `"%filename%"` within your error handler, or you could `call :errorlabel "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nS.csv"` and access the filename as `"%~1"` within your error handler.

Comment: Yep, I *do* want to exit the loop if an error occurs. How do I "assign the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable before the `GOTO`?

Comment: Same way you assigned every environmental variable that you already set in your script.

Comment: @marky, you mention that it is "`a folder of SQL scripts`", and that "`how to handle the error isn't my question`", but if you use `GOTO`'s on any of those three possible errors the `FOR` loop will end and no other `.sql` files will be processed?

Comment: @rojo, I used your SET suggestion and it works fine, thanks. (Thanks to Squashman and Compo, too)

Answer (score 0):

Based on part of rojo's first comment and my own, would this sort of structure not make more sense?

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "_INSTANCE=someinstance"
Set "_DATABASE=somedatabase"
Set "_SCRIPTFOLDER=D:\Scripts for Testing"
Set "_OUTPUTFOLDER=D:\Output for Testing"

If Not Exist "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%\" (Echo Output folder doesn't exist
    Timeout 3 /NoBreak >Nul
    GoTo :EOF)

If Not Exist "%_SCRIPTFOLDER%\*.sql" (Echo Source folder doesn't contain any SQL files
    Timeout 3 /NoBreak >Nul
    GoTo :EOF)

CD /D "%_SCRIPTFOLDER%" 2>Nul || (Echo Source folder, %_SCRIPTFOLDER%, is not available.
    Timeout 3 /NoBreak >Nul
    GoTo :EOF)

For %%A In (*.sql) Do (
    Echo Generating CSV: %%~nA.csv ...
    SQLCmd -b -S %_INSTANCE% -d %_DATABASE% -i "%%A" -s "|" -o "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nA.csv" -W 2>Nul && (
        Echo File created. Removing header dashes ...
        Findstr "[^-|]" "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nA.csv">"%_OUTPUTFOLDER%"\%%~nA.tmp" && (
            Move /Y "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%"\%%~nA.tmp" "%_OUTPUTFOLDER%\%%~nA.csv">Nul 2>&1 || (
                Echo A Move error occurred while moving %%~nA.tmp
                Timeout 2 /NoBreak >Nul)) || (Echo A FindStr error occurred while removing header dashes 
            Timeout 2 /NoBreak >Nul)) || (Echo A SQLCmd error occurred while processing the file %%~nS.csv
            Timeout 2 /NoBreak >Nul))
Pause
```

Comment: To my (very) inexperienced mind, that looks pretty complicated to me. I've got a working solution using @rojo's suggestion of `SET _VAR=<filename>` at the beginning of the `DO` portion of my `FOR` loop, so I'm going to stick with that for now. But I will take your code and learn from it, too!

Comment: @marky, it might look complicated to you, but it has built in safety, which yours doesn't, the `FindStr` and `Move` commands are better/more efficient and  it doesn't halt the entire process `If ErrorLevel 1` is true at any point!

Comment: I've no doubt it's safer and more efficient code - I'll definitely dig through it and learn from it! Thanks again.